# d3 - Show only values using d3.nest()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a `d3.nest()` function which gives me the below result.

```
[
  {
    "key": "one",
    "values": [
      {
        "date": 1385856000000,
        "values": 10
      },
      {
        "date": 1385942400000,
        "values": 20
      },
      {
        "date": 1386028800000,
        "values": 10
      },
      {
        "date": 1386115200000,
        "values": 17
      },
      {
        "date": 1386201600000,
        "values": 15
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "two",
    "values": [
      {
        "date": 1385856000000,
        "values": 18
      },
      {
        "date": 1385942400000,
        "values": 13
      },
      {
        "date": 1386028800000,
        "values": 18
      },
      {
        "date": 1386115200000,
        "values": 24
      },
      {
        "date": 1386201600000,
        "values": 26
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "three",
    "values": [
      {
        "date": 1385856000000,
        "values": 19
      },
      {
        "date": 1385942400000,
        "values": 22
      },
      {
        "date": 1386028800000,
        "values": 17
      },
      {
        "date": 1386115200000,
        "values": 16
      },
      {
        "date": 1386201600000,
        "values": 12
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "four",
    "values": [
      {
        "date": 1385856000000,
        "values": 35
      },
      {
        "date": 1385942400000,
        "values": 16
      },
      {
        "date": 1386028800000,
        "values": 18
      },
      {
        "date": 1386115200000,
        "values": 11
      },
      {
        "date": 1386201600000,
        "values": 10
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Function :

```
d3.csv('data.csv', function(data){
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = Date.parse(d.date)
            d.values = +d.values
        })

        var nest = d3.nest()
                    .key(function(d) { return d.label; })
                    .rollup(function (v) { return v.map(function (d) { delete d.label; return d; })})
                    .entries(data)

        d3.select('body').append('pre')
               .text(JSON.stringify(nest, null, '  '));
    })
```

Data :

```
label,date,values
one,2013-12-01,10
one,2013-12-02,20
one,2013-12-03,10
one,2013-12-04,17
one,2013-12-05,15
two,2013-12-01,18
two,2013-12-02,13
two,2013-12-03,18
two,2013-12-04,24
two,2013-12-05,26
three,2013-12-01,19
three,2013-12-02,22
three,2013-12-03,17
three,2013-12-04,16
three,2013-12-05,12
four,2013-12-01,35
four,2013-12-02,16
four,2013-12-03,18
four,2013-12-04,11
four,2013-12-05,10
```

My requirement is - in the result i do not want `date` and `values` labels to appear. I only want the values of `date` and `values` column to appear.

Example like this `1385856000000, 10`.

Is there any chance that I could get box brackets instead of curly brackets in the `values` list like this `[ 1385856000000, 10 ]` instead of `{ 1385856000000, 10 }`.

Will be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

Below function gave me the result.

```
d3.csv('data.csv', function(data){
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = Date.parse(d.date)
            d.values = +d.values
        })

        var nest = d3.nest()
                    .key(function(d) { return d.label; })
                    .rollup(function (v) { return v.map(function (d) { delete d.label; return [d.date, d.values]; })})
                    .entries(data)

        d3.select('body').append('pre')
               .text(JSON.stringify(nest, null, '  '));
    })
```